# Why isn't my sed operation working?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, vagrant

I'm provisioning a `virtual machin`e with `Vagrant`. 
This is my Vagrant output, **debug** mode, for my `Shell` script:

```
==> mom1: + enable_https
==> mom1: ++ cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/mom.anevis.solutions/.kpass
==> mom1: + local password=kvnilcFqq+sXmLlonoK1dM=
==> mom1: + sed -i 's,<property name="keyStorePassword" value="password" />,<property name="keyStorePassword" value="kvnilcFqq+sXmLlonoK1dM=" />,' /opt/activemq/conf/jetty.xml
```

It seems to be working fine, but when I check the file that was supposedly to be modified, it is empty!

```
<property name="keyStorePassword" value="" />
```

This is my Shell script:

```
enable_https(){
  local kpass=$(cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/company.com/.kpass)
  sed -i "s,<property name=\"keyStorePassword\" value=\"password\" />,<property name=\"keyStorePassword\" value=\"${kpass}\" />," /opt/activemq/conf/jetty.xml
}
```

The funny thing is that, when I try the same script locally, it works, but not when I try to use it during provision with Vagrant.

Any suggestion ? :)

Comment: It would appear the variable is empty even though it shows up in the debug. Does echoing it return a value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for further reference, my problem was that the same file which my `sed` was being applied, it was modified before, by another script. Which it means, my `sed` was correct, indeed. However it wasn't possible to apply it over the file, since this one wasn't the same anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this one out:
`sed -i "s/<property name=\"keyStorePassword\" value=\"password\" \/>/<property name=\"keyStorePassword\" value=\"${kpass}\" \/>/" /opt/activemq/conf/jetty.xml`

If it wont work, try replacing value `${kpass}` with some test text.

Comment: Thanks for that Sergey!